# Are stupid questions being asked to trick and fool SO members

Tags: discussion, questions

I often come a across a number of rather "stupid" questions. By "stupid" questions I mean for instances:

a) Questions posting a lot of code with a minimal description of the problem

or

b) Questions posting only parts of the relevant code.

I'm sure that this has been so for a long time and that is why SO has guidelines for asking good questions. Normally you can just post a comment and ask for further details and an update of the question, and OP will respond with an update.

However, the last 14 days I noticed several cases where OP doesn't respond in a meaningful way. For instance - if you ask for an input value, OP responds with something completely different.

I have a feeling that someone is playing tricks with SO members and trying to get them to waste time on artificial questions.

Am I being paranoid or have others experienced the same?

Comment: I think it's far more likely some askers just don't have a fundamental understanding of programming rather than they're wasting their time trying to annoy people on SO.

Comment: I've seen it happen, questions that are very clearly made-up. Very popular btw, if done right, important to present a problem that everybody can understand and yet has just the right amount of obscurity that it is somewhat plausible that it "doesn't work". The OP can ham it up in the comments, not that easy to keep up the spell. A waste of time of course, it peters out at ~8 votes and never gets a real answer. Doesn't happen enough to make it a big deal.  And greatly outnumbered by actually stoopid questions with an OP behind it that goes "oops" and walks away.

Comment: ["Never attribute to malice that which is adequately explained by stupidity"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon%27s_razor).

Comment: @approxiblue seems irony that you can ask stupid questions with malice

Comment: Elsewhere, there have long been (in)famous pro trolls on usenet who played to an art the fine line of asking stupid questions and just-enough-ambiguous followups which even regulars fell for repeatedly. At least SO has some moderation and reviews for a recourse.

Comment: This question itself is a little bit ambiguous (ironically enough :-)). Are you asking whether this phenomenon happens at all, or are you asking whether people agree that there has been a recent uptick in occurrences?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I've seen this happen. Trolls, spammers, extremely bored people, etc. have been known to post terrible questions that are not blatantly artificial.

In most cases, we don't actually have to do anything special: once closed or deleted they can't do much for spammers, and if folks refrain from commenting then the trolls remain unfed.

The worst outcome is usually someone trying to post an honest answer while others rant in the comments and the troll's / spammer's buddies prepare similarly misleading answers. Then it turns into a quagmire; someone trying to do the right thing is gonna have their time wasted.

So flag, close-vote, downvote, and move on.

Answer (score 4):

While spamming no doubt happens, I'd like to put in a word for patience and a stance of "innocent until proven guilty". With SO being an open interaction system reaching a global multicultural community, it's inevitable that some people will post badly-formed questions or not behave as others think is reasonable in the SO context. This can happen for any number of reasons: they're new and inexperienced, they're tired, they're frantic, etc., etc.  I'm not an apologist for spammers (in fact, quite the opposite); my comment simply comes from decades of working with computer users who are usually genuine but sometimes don't know any better or are acting in the moment.

Be aware also of the Baader-Meinhof phenomenon, a cognitive bias towards a tendency to overestimate the frequency of occurrences of something after having begun to notice it.

Comment: Good advice, but be wary of playing "Mother Teresa": putting extra work trying to save exceptionally bad questions tends to leave folks discouraged even if they're *not* being trolled. If you have to ask yourself, "is this stupidity or malice?" then perhaps just vote to close or downvote and move on; there is now a considerable amount of automatic guidance for the very lost, and the automated systems don't get frustrated nearly as easily as people.